# $K$ is a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where the area is $5$

Tags: calculus, matrices, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

Say that $K$ is a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where the area is $5$. Let
**B** = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 8 \\ 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix}

Find the area of the region **B**$K$.

Any starting hints? Is it possible to find the area given only a matrix like **B**?

Comment: $\mathbf BK$ is a weird notation to me, but I understand what it's supposed to mean.  Do you?

Comment: @Bye_World: Sort of, I suppose...but could you describe what you think it's supposed to mean?

Comment: Let $T$ be the linear transformation given by $\mathbf x \mapsto B\mathbf x$ (do you understand this notation?  It just means the vector $\mathbf x \in \Bbb R^2$ maps to some other vector given by the matrix multiplication $B\mathbf x$.), where $B$ is your matrix.  Then if you take any region in $\Bbb R^2$ -- and call it $K$ -- then $T(K)$ is just the image of that region under the linear transformation $T$.  Your problem is using $\mathbf B$ for both the matrix and the linear transformation.

Comment: This seems like a linear algebra I type question, so you're probably not supposed to prove this rigorously.  You just need to know that linear transformations transform areas (and volumes and higher dimensional analogs) by scaling them by $|\det(B)|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you define the area (and or the region), the proof techniques might differ, but in the end the idea is always the same : the determinant of the matrix is the multiplication factor for the area. In other words, if $K$ has area $\lambda$, then $BK$ has area $|\det B| \cdot \lambda$. I assume you can compute the determinant.

As for the proof, it is possible that your professor appealed to your intuition and didn't expect you to prove this part, mostly if you are in a first linear algebra course. It always ends up using the (Riemann or Lebesgue) integral and the fact that the area is defined using the integral of the indicator function of your region. Then you use the theorem for change of variables, and the determinant of the Jacobian naturally appears ; in this case the change of variables is $B$ and is linear, hence the determinant of the Jacobian matrix will simply be $|\det B|$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: If I'm understanding your hint correctly: $\det B = -14$, so would $BK = -70$?

Comment: @MathisLife it should be the absolute value $|\det B|$